# Latest "Legacy" PayPal SDK, no way to download it anymore?

Tags: paypal

Right now, if you want to develop against of PayPal platform the only way to do it - is to download the SDK from here https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index (of course, you can always just send raw HTTPS request following NVP protocol).

Before it was also possible to download "native" PayPal SDK (all of the samples on the x.com web site still use "legacy" PayPal SDK). Actually you can still download "native" API from the same download page as above, but they are only from February 2012, while the new API is auto-generated and a bit of verbose.

So, you are forced to use the new API whenever you want to develop anything for PayPal platform. Is it right way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always preferred using [my own class library](http://www.angelleye.com/overview-of-php-class-library-for-paypal/), but that's specific to PHP.  It makes it very simple to integrate nearly all of their services, and it's regularly maintained.

If you're working with something else I'd probably recommend just building your own class to handle things.  You might even end up pulling some functions out of their SDK, but you can set it all up the way that works best for you.

The only issue with their SDK's is that they're a large corporation, and when things need to be fixed/updated it can sometimes take months for them to get it done.  If you were working with your own you can get it done in a few min.

They provide a WSDL for working with SOAP, or you can also build NVP requests and work with their stuff directly.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. So, you don't know whether it is possible to download the latest (94 version) "legacy" SDK (right now it is only possible to download the New SDK). Probably they do it by purpose. The old SDK is not perfect at all, but for me it was easier to build my own libraries based on the old SDK.